# How do I parse a timestamp code in Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Is it possible to parse the timestamp code below into a required date format?

It is coming out with a timezone code that I want to remove, so I can insert it into our Google Sheets spreadsheet easily.

[image: code]

Comment: What is the data type of the values shown in the screenshot? Also, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: What's the required data format?

Comment: The required data format is xx/xx/xxxx. month/day/year @Cooper

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp is just a string.

```
function getMyDates() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getDisplayValues();
  //var html='';
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    let t=r[0].split(/-|T/);
    let d=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(t[0],t[1]-1,t[2]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");
    //html+='<br />' + d;
    sh.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(d);
  });
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Display Results");
}
```

Getting date strings in original format in column1 and putting them in column2

Comment: Well noted! Is this Javascript? Do you happen to know the proper code to insert into Apps Script. I'm going to try to work though it!